# How to get into Editor's Choice in apps for office

Tags: office-js

The Office 365 apps are hosted on Office store from where the new/existing users can access the app using Office applications like Excel/Word etc. We have a special category called Editor’s Choice on the Office store where some of the applications are suggested/recommended by the Microsoft for the better user experience.

Query:
I want to know the procedure as how to get our application registered under such category, if my application is already published on the Office store?

Comment: any update  on this request?

Answer (score 1):

It's a subjective human process and you can't buy your way in. It's about how popular, or good your app is.

If your app is unique, clever, or and editor likes it, then it's curated and chosen.

You can't choose, it's hand picked. That's why it's called "editor's choice"

While Apple relevant [here](http://arc.applause.com/2015/08/21/how-to-get-featured-in-the-app-store/)